# How to call(execute) a function, which name is stored in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, callback, execute

I want to execute a series of function IN C#.  These function names are stored in database
For example i have this functions :

Function1,Function2,Function3

I Want To run a query And the query give me back, for example, name of `Function1` & `Function2`

So the question is how can i run them when i retrieve them from database?

Or for example If my function names stored in an array.

I Want to call function in array index 2 and 4.  Just 2 & 4...And Them Excute Them

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx

Comment: where the actual implementation of these functions are stored?

Comment: Look into [`MethodInfo.Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke.aspx)

Comment: That's probably the worst design idea I've ever heard. But you can probably use reflection if you know in which class those methods are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string[] arr = { "func1", "func2" };
      System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Default2).GetMethod(arr[0]);
      if (methodInfo != null)
      {
          methodInfo.Invoke(this, null);
      }
  }
  public void func1()
  {
      Response.Write("func1");
  }
  public void func2()
  {
      Response.Write("func2");
  }
}
```

**Note:**

**access type** of function must be specified (public, private,protected).

Comment: Isn't this basically the same answer Jan W. posted, but without the extra info and LINQ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have your Functions in one class you could do the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(RunFunction("Function1"));
    }
    static object RunFunction(string functionName)
    {
        MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(CallableFunctions).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var callableFunctions = new CallableFunctions();
        return methodInfos.First(mi => mi.Name == functionName).Invoke(callableFunctions, null);
    }
}
class CallableFunctions
{
    public string Function1()
    {
        return "Abc";
    }
    public string Function2()
    {
        return "Def";
    }
}
```

The Method RunFunction executes the (parameterless) method in the class Callable Functions and prints it's return value

Be adviced that this can be a bad programming style. If you don't have a really good reason to do this, then don't

Remark:
Depending on what you are trying to achieve there are several other possibilites. You could write Stored Procedures/TVFs in the Sql Server, or if you are using MS-SQL you can create a CLR-Project for the Database and deploy C# Methods onto the SQL Server and execute them there. 
 Or you can conditionally execute branches based on the result.What you are trying to do here is potentially very dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a method to do that thing in generally.

If the names of the functions are known and limited, you can implement a function to switch each function by using a parameter which is passed to the function.
i.e. This is a pseudo code.

```
FUNCTION(INT functionCode)
    SWITCH(functionCode)
        CASE code1:
            CALL FUNCTION1
        CASE code2:
            CALL FUNCTION2
    END
END
```

Now you can parse a `functionCode` and call this wrapper function according to the results of your query. If you need to call more than one function, you can repeatedly call this wrapper function. But the problem is if you need to parse parameters to FUNCTION1, FUNCTION2 etc. In this case you have to bundle those parameters as an object and parse that also to the wrapper function.

This is generic answer. It seems first answer is focused on your question.